# ViewController gets misplaced, when a view size is adjusted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm quite new to the Xcode programming. I've added some view controller, labels, buttons and image view to my program, but, when I try to adjust, for example, the size of a label, the view controller that that label is in, gets displaced. I mean, when I try to drag the side of the label to change its size, the view controller moves down, making my label get displaced in the view controller. It is a very weird situation, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r74fcswtzvxfdmh/view%20controller.png) you have the screenshot of my project, the view controller misplaced is the one that says "Perfil" on the navigation bar. Every time I try to change one of those light blue views size, the entire view controller changes place. The more I try to change the side the more it will go down.
Sorry for my English, not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bigger issue is that you are using Table View Cells that are not part of a table view.

Table ViewCells are supposed to be a part of a UITableView and not just stuck in a view.

Using UITableViewCells in this way is what is causing the strange behavior.

If you are trying to make a table, put a UITableView in your view, and then you can customize the table view cells in there.

It you aren't trying to make a table, just use UIView's instead of those UITableViewCells.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas that may fix the problem:

First, if you're trying to drag and drop the label but the view controller moves instead, then you might just be grabbing the view controller's background by mistake. When this happened to me, it was because the order of my components in the xib file was wrong. Things are ordered from back to front, and when you click and drag something, you'll just be clicking and dragging whatever's on top. You can try and get past this by clicking the UI element on the left to be sure you select it, then dragging the handles.

It looks like you have things in a reasonable order, so that may not be the culprit at all.

Second, if that doesn't work, select the element you want to edit on the left, then open up the utilities pane on the right. Click the Attributes icon (should be fourth from the left) and look towards the bottom. You should see something like this:

[image: Setting location and size information]

Just manually edit the position and size of your labels there. You should see the change immediately reflected in the display.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Setting no autoresize behavior in Interface Builder solves the issue.**